# remove a boot option from Windows 7 menu (with grub)

Tags: windows-7, boot, grub, bcdedit, msconfig

I've an old eeepc that was shipped with Windows 7 starter installed, about a year ago (or more) I've installed a Debian/Linux using the Debian installer for Windows, everything went fine or so I believed (at the time I just didn't care much about) and I'm still using the Debian installed, but sometime now I boot also Windows.

The *annoying thing* is that the Debian installer left a menu option in the Windows boot menu, something like `continue the installation process`, the boot sequence now is `grub menu` -> `windows menu` -> `windows`.

I tried to edit the boot menu using `bcdedit` or `msconfig` like suggested in other answers but the first fail with something like `can't find the archive boot data configuration` the other show no menu options in the `boot` tab, is just empty.

I guess `grub` moved the boot somewhere Windows doesn't like (maybe I'm wrong).

So, any other way to remove this option from the Windows boot menu?

**update**

The installer left a `c:\win32-loader` directory (with Linux and the initrd image) and two files `g2ldr` `g2ldr.mbr` in `c:\` (which for my understanding are `grub` and the `mbr` used during the installation and still used when i choose the menu option `continue the installation process`)

**update 12/9**

output of Diskpart

```
Microsoft DiskPart versione 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
Nel computer MATRIX

DISKPART> select disk 0

Il disco attualmente selezionato è il disco 0.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partizione ###   Tipo              Dim.     Offset
  ---------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partizione 1    Primario           100 Mb  1024 Kb
  Partizione 2    Primario            97 Gb   101 Mb
  Partizione 0    Esteso             135 Gb    97 Gb
  Partizione 3    Logico             133 Gb    97 Gb
  Partizione 4    Logico            1912 Mb   230 Gb
  Partizione 5    Logico             136 Mb   232 Gb

DISKPART> select partition 1

La partizione attualmente selezionata è la partizione 1.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partizione 1
Tipo  : 07
Nascosta: No
Attiva: No
Offset in byte: 1048576

  Volume ###  Let. Etichetta    Fs     Tipo        Dim.     Stato      Info
  ---------   ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 0     D   Riservato p  NTFS   Partizione   100 Mb  Integro    Sistema

DISKPART> select partition 2

La partizione attualmente selezionata è la partizione 2.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partizione 2
Tipo  : 07
Nascosta: No
Attiva: No
Offset in byte: 105906176

  Volume ###  Let. Etichetta    Fs     Tipo        Dim.     Stato      Info
  ---------   ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partizione    97 Gb  Integro    Avvio

DISKPART> select partition 0

La partizione attualmente selezionata è la partizione 0.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partizione 0
Tipo  : 0F
Nascosta: No
Attiva: No
Offset in byte: 104987505152

Nessun volume associato alla partizione.

DISKPART> select partition 3

La partizione attualmente selezionata è la partizione 3.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partizione 3
Tipo  : 83
Nascosta: Sì
Attiva: Sì
Offset in byte: 104987506176

Nessun volume associato alla partizione.

DISKPART> select partition 4

La partizione attualmente selezionata è la partizione 4.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partizione 4
Tipo  : 82
Nascosta: Sì
Attiva: No
Offset in byte: 247910629376

Nessun volume associato alla partizione.
```

fdisk

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   205053659   102423406    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       205053721   488396799   141671539+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5   *   205053723   484199099   139572688+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6       484200448   488116223     1957888   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       488118272   488396799      139264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bcdedit` and pass it the `/store` argument such as `bcdedit /store c:\Boot\BCD` to list entries.

Importantly, the BCD file may not be on the C drive.

You may use the steps described at [Error message when you start Windows 7: "The Windows Boot Configuration Data file is missing required information"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2004518) to attempt to determine the correct partition.

Reproduced steps:

```
Partition C: might not be the correct volume letter.  Here is what we have to do to obtain the correct active partition:

If the Bootrec.exe tool cannot locate any missing Windows installations, you must remove the BCD store, and then you must re-create it.  Use the diskpart command to locate the volume letter for the system partition where the BCD store is located. To do this, follow these steps:

    At the command prompt type the following commands in the order which they are presented:
            c:\windows\system32> Diskpart
            DISKPART> select disk 0
            DISKPART> list partition
            DISKPART> select partition 1
            DISKPART> detail partition





Sample output for example:

Partition 1

Type  : 07

Hidden: No

Active: Yes

Offset in Bytes: 1048576



  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info

  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------

* Volume 1     D    System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System



The BCD store is located on the partition where the detail shows “Active : Yes”, and Info is “System”.  The partition may have a label “System Reserved”.   In this example, Volume 1 is the system partition and Windows has temporarily assigned the volume letter D.  If partition 1 is not marked Active, then select partition 2, and view the detail to see whether the next partition is Active and the Info is System.   A partition with Info as “Boot”, is the partition where the \Windows directory is located.

Partition 2

Type  : 07

Hidden: No

Active: No

Offset in Bytes: 105906176



  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info

  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------

* Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition    100 GB  Healthy    Boot

On Windows Vista, one partition is typically used as both the System and Boot partitions and the \boot\BCD store is located on the same volume where the \Windows directory is located.  On Windows 7, separate partitions are used for the System and Boot partitions to make it easier to enable BitLocker Drive Encryption and to support computers that have UEFI firmware.
```

Comment: Thank you but there's not such directory or file `c:\Boot\BCD`, I searched for any `BCD` file on `c:\` but nothing.

Comment: The file will be `\Boot\BCD` on the partition marked active within the partition table. This may not be the C drive. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2004518 where method 2 describes how to find where the file is.

Comment: @Alex any luck finding the correct file and removing the unwanted entry?

Comment: sorry for the delay, a bit busy, given a try yet, there is a primary partition active but is probably linux, the disk manager doesn't let me assign a letter. Does Windows 7 Starter have other path names for partitions?

Comment: Please provide the output of diskpart commands above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ssnobody, the `BCD` was in `d:\Boot\BCD` as you told, just hidden (`dir /a` needed), I failed to backup the `BCD` using `/store d:\Boot\BCD /export c:\BCD.bak` but managed to remove the `continue installation` entry.